# How can find the repeated values in the given two arrays without nested foreach loops?

Tags: c#, arrays, nested-loops

I want to find the repeated values in two different arrays.

I'm trying not to repeat code and am always interested in shorter ways to implement things. As I mentioned at the title in the method that I wrote below, a foreach loop is used twice and they are nested.

Can I write this code without nesting the foreach loops in way that's as short or shorter?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Arrays to find the repeated values in both arrays
            int[] array1 = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int[] array2 = new int[8] { 3, 5, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17 };

            //Final Array
            int[] array3 = findTheIntersect(array1, array2);

            foreach (int item in array3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item}, Array Length: {array3.Length}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static int[] findTheIntersect(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
        {
            //Size of the final array
            int arrSize = 0;
            //Item variable that we will add to final array
            int arrItem = 0;
            //Temporary List to store repeated items
            List<int> arrList = new List<int>();

            foreach (int number in arr1)
            {
                int x = number;

                foreach (int number1 in arr2)
                {
                    int y = number1;

                    if (y == x && !arrList.Contains(number1))
                    {
                        arrSize++;
                        arrItem = number1;
                        arrList.Add(arrItem);
                    }

                }
            }

            int[] finalArr = new int[arrSize];
            finalArr = arrList.ToArray();

            return finalArr;
        }
```

When I searched for existing solutions, I only found answers for repeating values in just one array, rather than comparing two different arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LINQ (`System.Linq`) one-liner, use [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersect-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))). Just remember that the position of the element in the list isn't taken into account.

```
int[] duplicates = array1.Intersect(array2).ToArray();
```